# Cannot add custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme

**I have tried to create an custom theme, my order structure is like this:**

> app/design/frontend/Steiner/Josef/

**In "Steiner" i got:**

```
 1. -composer.json
 2. -registration.php
```

> and in "Josef" i got:

```
 1. -theme.xml
```

i flushed the cache, done an upgrade, compile, static deploy nothing seems to work still no theme appear on admin page.

The Magento Folder is completly empty i cannot find the other Themes like "Luma".
I have downloaded Magento 2.3.4 directly from the Magento Homepage and not Github.
How do i create an custom Theme now?

Answer (score 0):

Create the **theme.xml** in

> app/design/frontend/Steiner/Josef/

To your theme directory

> app/design/frontend/Steiner/Josef/

Configure it using the following example:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Magestore Simple Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

Add **registration.php** in

> app/design/frontend/Steiner/Josef/

To register your theme in the system, in your theme directory add a **registration.php** file with the following content:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Steiner/Josef',
    __DIR__
);
```

Also, **composer.json** is should be in the `app/design/frontend/Steiner/Josef/`